# How can I sort my records by average rating?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sorting

I have a table of venues which I'm displaying on the venues index page as partials. I also have a table of reviews where one venue can have many reviews and each review has a rating 1-5.

I'm trying to get the venues to display on the index page with the ones with the highest average rating at the top and descending.

The controller code looks like this:

**Venues controller**

```
def index
    if
      @venues = Venue.with_type(params[:venuetypes]).with_area(params[:areas]).joins(:reviews).order("reviews.rating DESC")
    else
      @venues = Venue.all
    end
  end
```

This gives this kind of a result:

- If venue 1 has a 5 star review it
  shows the venue partial at the top of
  the list.
- If venue 2 has a 5 star review and
  a 1 star review it shows two
  partials, one at the top and one
  at the bottom of the list.
- If venue 3 has a 5 star review, a 3 star review and
  a 1 star review it shows three
  partials, one at the top, one in the middle and one
  at the bottom of the list.

I just want one partial showing per venue but positioned in the list by the average rating, I feel theres a .average or something missing somewhere how can I acheive this?

Thanks for any help its much appreciated!

**edit**

**Venue model**

```
class Venue < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :addressline1, :addressline2, :addressline3, :addressline4, :postcode, :phonenumber, :about, :icontoppx, :iconleftpx, :area_id, :venuetype_id, :lat, :long, :venuephotos_attributes
  belongs_to :area
  belongs_to :venuetype
  has_many :reviews
  has_many :venuephotos

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :venuephotos, :allow_destroy => true

  scope :with_type, lambda { |types|
    types.present? ? where(:venuetype_id => types) : scoped }

  scope :with_area, lambda { |areas|
    areas.present? ? where(:area_id => areas) : scoped }

  def to_param
    "#{id}-#{name.gsub(/\W/, '-').downcase}"
  end

  def add_rating(rating_opts)
    @venue.add_rating(:rating => rating, :reviewer => params[:rating][:reviewer])
    self.reviews.create(rating_opts)
    self.update_rating!
  end

  def update_rating!
    s = self.reviews.sum(:rating)
    c = self.reviews.count
    self.update_attribute(:average_rating, s.to_f / c.to_f)
    self.save(:validate => false)
  end
end
```

**Development log for adding a review**

```
Started POST "/venues/44-rating-test-5/reviews" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-05-18 09:24:24 +0100
  Processing by ReviewsController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"âœ“", "authenticity_token"=>"GZWd67b5ocJOjwKI6z9nJInBXxvQahHrjUtUpdm9oJE=", "review"=>{"rating"=>"5", "title"=>"5 star review"}, "venue_id"=>"44-rating-test-5"}
  [1m[36mVenue Load (1.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT `venues`.* FROM `venues` WHERE (`venues`.`id` = 44) LIMIT 1[0m
  [1m[35mUser Load (0.0ms)[0m  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE (`users`.`id` = 3) LIMIT 1
  [1m[36mSQL (0.0ms)[0m  [1mBEGIN[0m
  [1m[35mSQL (2.0ms)[0m  describe `reviews`
  [1m[36mAREL (0.0ms)[0m  [1mINSERT INTO `reviews` (`title`, `created_at`, `updated_at`, `venue_id`, `user_id`, `rating`) VALUES ('5 star review', '2011-05-18 08:24:24', '2011-05-18 08:24:24', NULL, 3, 5)[0m
  [1m[35mSQL (27.0ms)[0m  COMMIT
  [1m[36mSQL (0.0ms)[0m  [1mBEGIN[0m
  [1m[35mAREL (0.0ms)[0m  UPDATE `reviews` SET `venue_id` = 44, `updated_at` = '2011-05-18 08:24:24' WHERE (`reviews`.`id` = 90)
  [1m[36mSQL (23.0ms)[0m  [1mCOMMIT[0m
  [1m[35mSQL (1.0ms)[0m  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `reviews` WHERE (`reviews`.venue_id = 44)
  [1m[36mUser Load (0.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE (`users`.`id` = 3) LIMIT 1[0m
Rendered reviews/_review.html.erb (9.0ms)
Rendered reviews/create.js.erb (22.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 220ms (Views: 56.0ms | ActiveRecord: 54.0ms)
```

**edit**
**create review method (reviews controller)**

```
def create
    @review = current_user.reviews.create!(params[:review])
    @review.venue = @venue
    if @review.save
      flash[:notice] = 'Thank you for reviewing this venue!'
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to venue_path(@venue) }
        format.js
      end
    else
      render :action => :new
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To add to [NoICE's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6008015/how-can-i-sort-my-records-by-average-rating/6008739#6008739), by hooking into the `:after_add` and `:after_remove` [association callbacks](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html), you don't have to remember to call a special `add_rating` method.

```
class Venue < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :reviews, :after_add => :update_average_rating, :after_remove => :update_average_rating

  def update_average_rating(review=nil)
    s = self.reviews.sum(:rating)
    c = self.reviews.count
    self.update_attribute(:average_rating, c == 0 ? 0.0 : s / c.to_f)
  end

end
```

Also, you'll want to check count for 0 to prevent division by zero.

When you create the review, you must append with `<<` or `concat` it to the venue object's `reviews` association so that the callback gets triggered. For example, this will associate the review to the venue, create the review (INSERT into the db), and trigger the callback:

```
@venue = Venue.find(params[:venue_id])
@venue.reviews << Review.new(params[:review])
```

This will create the review but *won't* trigger the callback, even if the `venue_id` is the params:

```
Review.create(params[:review])
```

If you really want to get your action to trigger the callback, you can change your code to:

```
def create
  @review = Review.new(params[:review].merge({ :user => current_user, :venue => @venue })
  if @review.valid? and @venue.reviews << @review
  ...
```

To fix it expediently, though, you could just add `@review.venue.update_average_rating` just before the line w/ `flash[:notice]`.

Comment: Hey, thanks! Didn't know about :after_add and :after_remove callbacks, very useful! :) (p.s. division by zero check also comes handy :D )

Comment: p.s. I've solved these things in the past with after_save in Rating model :) but this is much much cleaner

Comment: @NoICE You're welcome. There are an infinite number of tricks like this. I've been doing Rails full-time for over a year now, and still learning.

Comment: @Jonathan Tran, I've added the :after_add call but its still not updating the average_rating field in the venue's record I've tried moving the update_average_rating method to the controller and changing the last line to Venue.find(params[:id]).update_attribute(:average_rating, c == 0 ? 0.0 : s / c.to_f) but still nothing, I've added the development log for when a review is added to my question, could it be something to do with the add review method using a javascript function?

Comment: @Dave Updated answer w/ example of triggering the callbacks. Don't define `update_average_rating` in your controller; it belongs in the model class since it has to do with your data-model. If you need to invoke it manually, do `Venue.find(params[:id]).update_average_rating`.

Comment: @Jonathan Tran, I'm not sure how to work that callback request into my create reviews method. I've added it to my question, if I add it on its own line it works fine except it fails to save user_id of the writer

Answer (score 4):

If I understand correctly, you have model venue, which have has_many :reviews, and each review has collumn "rating".

I'm oferring alternative code for example given by Michael which should be a LOT MORE faster and millions-of-records ready, but it requires some processing then review is added (covered in this example), which give you huge performance boost when the records are selected, ordered and shown:

Create a migration which adds average_rating as float:

```
add_collumn :venues, :average_rating, :float, :default => 0.0, :null => false
add_index :venues, :average_rating
```

Now, in your controller:

```
# perhaps add paginate at the end instead of .all ...
@venues = Venue.with_type(params[:venuetypes]).with_area(params[:areas]).order("average_rating DESC").all
```

The model updated:

```
class Venue < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :reviews

  # you'll need to create ratings for this venue via this method, so everything is atomic
  # and transaction safe
  # parameter is hash, so you can pass as many review parameters as you wish, e.g.
  # @venue.add_rating(:rating => rating, :reviewer => params[:rating][:reviewer])
  # or
  # @venue.add_rating(params[:rating])
  # :)
  def add_rating(rating_opts)
    # you can of course add as 
    self.reviews.create(rating_opts)
    self.update_rating!
  end

  # let's update average rating of this venue
  def update_rating!
    s = self.reviews.sum(:rating)
    c = self.reviews.count
    self.average_rating = s.to_f / c.to_f
    self.save(:validate => false)
    # or you can use .update_attribute(:average_rating, s.to_f / c.to_f)
  end

end
```

Hope this helps. Please ask if you have any questions.

Regards, NoICE

Comment: PS. there also should be way to do this via pure SQL, but then you would need sub-query and group by clause... which will create "temporary tables" on the SQL server side, which is very slow and can kill your server when you have lots of records.

Comment: @NoICE, thanks for the great answer I'll give it a go when I get back from work

Comment: @NoICE, I'm having a problem with the average_rating field, it's not changing from the defult 0.0, I can add new venues and set an average_rating for them from the console and it works great, the field just wont change when reviews are added. I've added the code you wrote into my question as I have placed it in my app (I'm super new to this so may have made a daft mistake)

Comment: Hello, in my example, you must create reviews by calling @venue.add_rating(options_for_review) ... Well I admit this isn't best solution (nor naming of the methods), but as @Jonathan Tran suggested, you can call this method via :after_add and :after_remove as he shows, very useful thing indeed! :)

Comment: @NoICE, I've added the :after_add call but its still not updating the average_rating field in the record I've tried moving the update_average_rating method to the controller and changing the last line to Venue.find(params[:id]).update_attribute(:average_rating, c == 0 ? 0.0 : s / c.to_f) but still nothing, I've added the development log for when a review is added to my question

Answer (score 0):

You could create an `average_rating` method on `Venue` and then simply:

```
@venues = Venue.with_type(params[:venuetypes]).with_area(params[:areas]).includes(:reviews).sort_by(&:average_rating).reverse
```

The method:

```
class Venue
  def average_rating
    ratings = reviews.map(&:rating)
    ratings.sum.to_f / ratings.size
  end
end
```

This solution is probably not optimal if there's a huge number of records or if performance is critical, but it's very simple and it works.

Comment: thanks for having a look, theats just the sort of thing i'm after but it returns a undefined method `include' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x41095b0> error

Comment: Sorry it's `includes` with a `s`. I fixed the answer. But it's not needed: it only reduces the number of queries.

Answer (score 0):

Let us suppose that reviews are editable, then no answers work well. So I have done like below.

```
class Venue < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :reviews, :dependent => :delete_all
end
```

And now in Reviews model as below.

```
class Venue < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :venue

    # If reviews are editable
    after_save :update_average_rating 

    # If reviews are deletable
    before_destroy :update_average_rating 

    private
      def update_average_rating
       s = self.venue.reviews.sum(:rating)
       c = self.venue.reviews.count
       self.venue.update_attribute(:average_rating, c == 0 ? 0.0 : s / c.to_f)
  end
end
```