# Eager-loading most recent item of a has-many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, has-many, eager-loading

I have two models: `Conversation` and `Message`.  A message belongs_to a conversation, and a conversation has_many messages:

```
# conversation.rb
class Conversation < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :messages
end

# message.rb
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :conversation
end
```

I have an interface that is going to list all the conversations, but I also want to include the "most recent" message associated with the conversation through eager-loading.

Do I need to create a new has_one or belongs_to relationship between the conversation and the message that will track the most recent message?  Or is there a way I can do this through a scope using joins/includes?

**Edit:** The problem is that I don't want a SQL query to be executed for every iteration of this loop:

```
# controller
@conversations = Conversation.all

# view
@conversations.each do |conversation|
  most_recent_message = conversation.messages.last
  # ...
end
```

**Edit 2:** I also tried to do the following, unsuccessfully.  The goal was to add a `last_message_id` column to the conversations table, allowing it to reference the last added message.

```
# migration
add_column :conversations, :last_message_id, :integer

# conversation.rb
belongs_to :last_message, :class_name => 'Message'

# message.rb
after_create :set_last_message_on_conversation

def set_last_message_on_conversation
  self.conversation.last_message = self
  self.conversation.save!
end
```

However, that results in a SQL error since the last_message_id is null when the conversation is created.  (I was hoping that it would all take place in a transaction, and that the last_message_id would be updated before the transaction completed, but I think it's a MySQL/MyISAM issue where transactions are not used.)

> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql::Error: Column 'last_message_id' cannot be null: INSERT INTO `conversations` (`last_message_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) VALUES (NULL, '2011-05-31 16:57:11', '2011-05-31 16:57:11')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use another association:

```
# conversation.rb
class Conversation < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :messages
  has_one :last_message, :class_name => "Message", :order => "created_at DESC"
end

# controller
@conversations = Conversation.includes(:last_message)

# view
@conversations.each do |conversation|
  most_recent_message = conversation.last_messages
  # ...
end
```

Be warned that `last_message` and `messages` and considered independent associations. If you use `conversation.messages`, the messages will be loaded from the database. And if you change an attribute of `last_message`, it won't affect `messages.last` until reload.

**Edit:** Actually, according to the log, ActiveRecord still loads all the conversations' messages. Probably because it can't "LIMIT 1" like it does when it's not eager loaded.

So in terms of SQL requests, this solution seems to be equivalent to simply using `Conversation.includes(:messages)`. But maybe Rails doesn't process the extra results when using the `has_one` association.

Comment: Looks like this is the closest I'm going to get, I suppose!  The only problem I see is a memory issue in that it loads *all* the messages associated with a conversation when I just want *one* for each conversation.

Comment: If this is really a problem, storing the `last_message_id` can work. This answer shows one way of doing it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6008015/how-can-i-sort-my-records-by-average-rating/6025838#6025838

Answer (score 0):

In what sense do you mean lazy-loading?  Just that the most recent message isn't loaded when the conversation is loaded?  Try this:

```
class Conversation < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :messages, :order => "created_at"
end
```

Then you could call

```
@conversation.messages.last
```

which is executing SQL like

```
SELECT "messages".* FROM "messages" WHERE ("messages".conversation_id = 129) ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1
```

at the time that you actually ask for the last message.

**IMPORTANT**: if you have called @conversation.messages previous to this during the action's execution, it may have loaded all of the messages already, and so may not hit the database again when you call @conversation.messages.last.  So if a message was added between the call to @conversation.messages and @conversation.messages.last, you would not be getting the truly last one.  But I imagine that's probably ok?

Comment: I updated the question with the problem I'm trying to avoid, and specifically why the `@conversation.messages.last` solution won't work.

Comment: What you're really looking for, then, is eager-loading. You'd like to load all conversations with their last messages in one or two SQL queries.  I will delete my answer later and perhaps try again, but I don't think it's simple.  You can make a has_one association to get the last message, but then when you go to eager load it for all conversations, the generated SQL pulls all messages and that's no good.

Comment: Thanks for the correction.  I updated my question and tags to read "eager-loading" instead of "lazy-loading".